# How can I fix my pip installation on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pip

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 and python3.5 and i tried installing and upgrading pip

As pip3 is not supported on 3.5 anymore i got it screwed up with import and syntax errors.

I now managed to finally install pip3 and upgrade it to a supported version with this command
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.0
And executing "python3 -m pip -V" results in this:

pip 19.0 from /home/hreich/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

But now when i execute pip3 -V or any pip3 command in the console i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
 ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Can i fix this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command uninstalled pip and reinstalled it which resolved the same issue for me:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```